# jQuery No Conflict Mode for extra functions

Tags: jquery

I'm sure this is a simple question, just can't seem to get it to work right.

I was having some conflicts with jQuery, so I used the aliasing feature mentioned in the official documentation.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.loadmore').addClass('hidden'); // works fine!

  loadmore();

});

function loadmore(){
  $('.loadmore').addClass('hidden'); // doesn't work!
}
```

How do I get the aliasing to work for my code that I threw into functions for better organization and for the ability to reuse? I'm currently using `jQuery` instead of `$` for everything due to the issue presented in the sample above. Thought I could save a few bits of data and use the alias that's shown in all the tutorials.

Comment: how about if you use "jQuery" instead of "$" in the line inside function loadmore()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery no conflict mode essentially sets the `$` function to a different name, like so:

```
$('select something').doSomethingElse(); // Works
var $j = jQuery.noConfilct();
$('select something').doSomethingElse(); // Doesn't work
$j('select something').doSomethingElse(); // Works
```

If you don't want to use a name other than `$` for jQuery you can do this:

```
(function ($) {
    $('selector').doSomething();
    $('another selector').doSomethingElse();
}(jQuery));
```

This makes `jQuery = $`, but only inside of the parenthesis, allows you work as usual, and never causes conflicts.

Comment: Nice! I like the idea of the first option better. One question though. Do I just declare the `var $j = jQuery.noConfilct();` before my document ready function and I'll be good to use `$j` anywhere in that JS file?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this...

```
(function($) {

// Put all your jQuery here... and you can use $

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you could pass `$` to your function.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.loadmore').addClass('hidden'); // works fine!

    loadmore($);

});

function loadmore($){
    $('.loadmore').addClass('hidden'); // should work fine too!
}
```

Comment: first off, thanks! But one question, will I still be able to pass additional variables through? For instance, `loadmore($, num);` and receive it like this `function loadmore($, num) { }`